# How can I reverse natural scrolling on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, xmodmap, scrolling

I tried to change the `.Xmodmap` file as

```
pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

but natural scrolling was not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to

- System Settings> Mouse & Touchpad.

In touchpad sections, uncheck the natural scrolling options.

Answer (score 0):

disable the natural scrolling in touchpad settings and you are good to go..